# PHP: how to specify directory names with PATH_SEPARATOR in open_basedir?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, configuration

On non-Windows systems PHP's [PATH_SEPARATOR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant is a colon... unfortunately I have to deal with a running system which has lots of existing virtualhosts and directories with colons in their name (they contain ip address and port in the standard a.b.c.d:p notation).

We do have a new naming scheme without colons in paths but I cannot switch existing virtualhosts overnight. Is it possible somehow to escape the colon or otherwise find a method to specify those directory names in PHP's [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) ?

I'd like build Apache VirtualHost configurations with stuff like:

```
  php_admin_value open_basedir "/w/1.2.3.4:80/www.acme.com/htdocs"
```

We're currently running PHP-5.3.15 as a module of Apache-2.2.23

EDIT: I do have tried, without success, to escape colons with backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53687

Have you tried escaping it, e.g.

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/w/1.2.3.4\:80/www.acme.com/htdocs"
```

Comment: Oh lol I did not even remember that BR - it was actually mine (I had a try with this system two years ago). Anyway escaping with backslashes does not help, I clarified it in the question.

Comment: Nice ;) But then it might be difficult to find a solution easily.

Comment: Seems like the only correct answer is "it's not possible", so I'm accepting this answer that refers to the BR opened by myself :D